# Python вывод ошибки в except

Tags: python, исключения

Использую Python 3.6.8

Интересует как вывести внутри except причину ошибки.

Надеюсь объяснил понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
try:
  0 / 0
except Exception as e: 
  print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [7]: import traceback

In [8]: try:
   ...:     5 / 0
   ...: except ZeroDivisionError as e:
   ...:     traceback.print_exc()
   ...:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-8-7e0b4de302f2>", line 2, in <module>
    5 / 0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

В отличии от `print(e)`, `print_exc` выводит немного больше информации о том что случилось.