# Проблема с pyOWM, не может найти город

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyowm

```
import time
import telebot
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils import config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps
from pyowm.owm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'
    
owm = OWM('token', config_dict)
mgr = owm.weather_manager() 
bot = telebot.TeleBot("token")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_echo(message):
    
    if message.text == "/start":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, напиши название города, а я тебе напишу погоду:)" "\n")
        time.sleep(3)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Меня обновляют каждый день")
        return True
    elif message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добро пожаловать, напиши название города, а я тебе напишу погоду:)")
        return True
    else:
        try:
            observation = mgr.weather_at_place(message.text)
            w = observation.weather
            status = w.detailed_status
            temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']
            temp1 = w.temperature('celsius')['temp_max']
            rain = w.rain
            humidity = w.humidity
            wind = w.wind()['speed']

            answer = "Статус: " + status + "\n"
            answer += "Максимальная температура : " + str(temp1) + "C°\n"
            answer += "Температура сейчас: " + str(temp) + "C°\n"
            answer += "Влажность: " + str(humidity) + "%\n"
            answer += "Скорость ветра: " + str(wind) + "м/с\n"
            if temp < 11:
                answer += "Сейчас очень холодно."
            elif temp < 20:
                answer += "Сейчас прохладно, лучше одеться потеплее."
            else:
                answer += "Температура в норме!"        
        
            bot.reply_to(message, answer)
        except:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Ошибка! Город не найден.')

bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

> Не показывает погоду в городе

Comment: Показанный вами код не может выдать сообщение «Не показывает погоду в городе». Что конкретно происходит и после каких конкретно действий?

Comment: когда пишу название города срабатывает except, а должно найти город и вывести погоду

Comment: А ещё мы теперь можем управлять вашим телеграм-ботом, потому что вы показали секретный токен

Comment: Если срабатывает except, значит напишите в нём код для вывода текста ошибки, а не скрывайте её за сообщением «Город не найден»

Comment: bot.polling(none_stop = True)
SyntaxError: expected 'except' or 'finally' block
вот ошибка

Comment: Показанный вами код не может выводить такую ошибку

Comment: как вывести ошибку?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1156700